# Perplexed by Python logging

Tags: python, python-logging

I started using Python `logging` to tidy up the messages generated by some code.  I have the statement

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='my_log.log', filemode='w', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.INFO)
```

in the `main` Python module and was expecting the log file to be created from scratch every time the program runs.  However, Python appends the new messages to the existing file.  I wrote the program below to try to test what is going on but now I don't get a log file created and the messages appear in the console (Spyder 5).  I am running `WinPython 3.9` on a Windows 10 machine.

```
import datetime
import logging 

logging.basicConfig(filename='my_log.log', filemode='w', level=logging.INFO)

t = datetime.datetime.now()
logging.info("Something happened at %s" % t)
```

All suggestions welcome - thanks!

Update: following @bzu's suggestion, I changed my code to this:

```
import datetime
import logging 

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.FileHandler('my_log.log', 'w')
logger.addHandler(handler)

t = datetime.datetime.now()
logging.info("Something happened at %s" % t)
```

This created the log file but nothing was written to it.  If I change the final line to
`logger.info("Something happened at %s" % t)`
the the message appears in the log file.  However, I want to log the messages from different modules which `import logging` and so know about logging in general but I don't know how they can access the specific `logger` object

Comment: Try `filemode='w+'` in the basic configuration

Comment: Hi @Buzz - adding `filemode='w+'` did not seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching on the web, adding `force=True` to `logging.basicConfig` seemed to solve the problem ie:
`logging.basicConfig(filename='my_log.log', filemode='w', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.INFO, force=True)`

Answer (score 1):

If you run the program with plain python (`python log_test_file.py`), it should work as expected.

I suspect that the problem with Spyder is, that it overrides the `logging` module config.

To avoid this kind of problems, the recommended way is to use custom logger per file:

```
import logging 

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# boilerplate: can be converted into a method and reused
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='my_log.log', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info("Something happened")
```